# Dealing with OpenGL errors at runtime

Tags: c++, opengl

Let's say I'm writing a wrapper for an OpenGL object. When dealing with exception safety, I want to account for OpenGL errors too (i.e., when one occurs, a method calling the OpenGL function returns an error code or throws an exception). The intent for that is **not** debugging during a debug build, but for handling any possible errors during runtime of a release build. Are there any ways to achieve that?

I'm not sure about using the debug output for more than logging in a debug build, while `glGetError` feels a bit weird and unreliable altogether.

Comment: What you try to do is completely superfluous and waste of time. You are not the first one who needs some OpenGL [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output).

Comment: have a look at [glIntercept](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/GLIntercept/) its like using `glGetError` for each GL code line  ... but without changing code ... but to lokalize a problem you should add a markers into gl code so you know which calls are executed from which part of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say I'm writing a wrapper for an OpenGL object.

Step 1: Don't do that. I know that sounds flippant, but please don't. I can understand wanting a managed object type, like a `unique_ptr` but for OpenGL objects. But any wrapping beyond that will almost certainly harm you far more than it helps. Especially if the abstraction is wrong. The interactions between OpenGL objects and mechanisms are generally not suitable for this sort of thing.

You will get far more out of employing OpenGL [direct state access](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access) calls directly than wrapping OpenGL functions behind some object interface. Your code doesn't magically get better just by using member functions.

> when one occurs, a method calling the OpenGL function returns an error code or throws an exception

Step 2: Don't do that either. Most OpenGL errors are usage errors (that is, you used the API incorrectly). And usage errors should *not* be handled as C++ exceptions. Exceptions should be for conditions like invalid input or a texture with an unexpected format. Things that come from outside of the code. Using exceptions to handle programming errors is generally not a useful idea.

If you need to debug an OpenGL application, there are basically two ways to handle it. For day-to-day verification, you should use [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) to log any errors that you get. This is especially useful for "release" type builds (though you still need to use a [debug context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Debug_contexts) to ensure debug output support).

Should you get an error, you can then load up Renderdoc or a similar tool which can tell you exactly where the error was generated. Alternatively, you can setup debug output so that it gives you synchronous error messages instead of async errors, so you can just breakpoint in the middle of where the error came from. Either way, you ought to be able to easily track it down with minimal specialized code and most importantly, no function wrappers.

Indeed, Renderdoc and similar tools are far more useful for tracking down OpenGL errors in release builds than anything one could reasonably write oneself. You can get a trace of all your OpenGL calls, with the parameter values and the like. It's just a better way to handle errors.

Comment: Is creation of a debug context for a release build an acceptable practice? Does OpenGL get a performance boost if you provide it a non-debug context?

Comment: I must say that this type of thinking is why end users get dead-end errors when playing video games and when using software in general. For example, which error would you rather get: Call to function glLoad failed, or "program crashed unexpectedly"?
Sometimes a specific graphics card might just not support a specific functionality, then getting a detailed error message is crucial- even in release builds!